# Angular 2 proper way to template a [routerLink] in a child component

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

## I am trying to find the way to template a [routerLink] in a child component.

In my `app.component` i have have the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`.

Now, inside `otherModule.component` I am trying to apply a `<a [routerLink]="['home']">Home</a>`.

### app.module:

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {HomeModule} from "../home/home.module";
import {OtherModule} from "../otherModule/otherModule.module";
import {RouterModule} from "@angular/router";
import {routes} from "./routes";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HomeModule,
    HttpModule,
    OtherModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

### routes:

```js
import {HomeComponent} from "../login/login.component";
import {OtherComponent} from "../clickStudio/clickStudio.component";

export const routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'other', component: OtherComponent },

]
```

### other.component:

```js
import {Component} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: 'other',
  template: `<a [routerLink]="['home']">Home</a>`,
  styleUrls: ['./clickstudio-menu.component.scss']
})
export class OtherComponent {

}
```

#### My main problem is that i need to route the *root* router and not the chilren routes

- What are the best practices to implement this?
- Any way to keep the binding to the routerLink?

Comment: What do you mean by "keep the binding to the routerLink" ?

Comment: @Lior G what do you mean by keep binding to the router link?  
what you are doing seems correct.  Since your `OtherModule` is added in imports, the root routes will be accessible to `OtherComponent`. ForRoot() and ForChild() separate root routes from child routes.  Go through "https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#link-parameters-array" for more details.

Comment: I am trying to bind the router link to a variable to keep an option to add async dynamic routs by accesing the 'home' variable and assign them later on

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried

```
<a routerLink="home">Details</a>
```

or

```
<a routerLink="/home">Details</a>
```

Comment: Your two lines are the same.

Comment: Thanks, it is working, though i'm looking for a way to keep the binding.